# Simulate partially pressed keys in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, custom-controls

Is it possible to simulate an analog keyboard or the behavior of a joystick in vb.net? A traditional keyboard can only be pressed on or off however a joystick or analog keyboard will have the input to lets say a game depend of the amount of pressure or how far the analog stick is moved. I would like to be able to press a button on my regular keyboard and then have the program simulate lets say a 50% press from an analog keyboard. Is this even possible and how would I approach a solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-keyboard-input-works):

> As listed previously, there are 3 keyboard related events that can
>   occur on a control. The following sequence shows the general order of
>   the events:
>
> 1. > The user pushes the "a" key, the key is preprocessed, dispatched, and
>    >     a KeyDown event occurs.
> 2. > The user holds the "a" key, the key is preprocessed, dispatched, and a
>    >     KeyPress event occurs. This event occurs multiple times as the user holds a key.
> 3. > The user releases the "a" key, the key is preprocessed, dispatched and a KeyUp event occurs.

Given that Key Down is an either/or event (at whatever threshold the key makes contact with the keyboard it fires an event) there isn't a way with Window OS / vb.net to register a partial key press.

In some work I did in the past, I used a joystick simulator (called [vJoy](https://github.com/shauleiz/vJoy)) to simulate movements of a joystick that could be anywhere between 0% and 100% of range of motion. But again, that won't work with keyboard keys b/c the operating system itself only recognizes the three events above.